# My Android Studio project works on Lollipop but doesn't work on Kitkat

Tags: java, android, layout, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an Android Studio project that is working fine on devices with Android build version Lollipop but is throwing an exception when trying to run it on a device with android build version Kitkat. This is my project's build.gradle file:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.avi.phoenixinfotech"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

and here is the log of error I am getting when I run the application on a Kitkat device:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.avi.phoenixinfotech/com.example.avi.phoenixinfotech.MainActivity}:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.avi.phoenixinfotech.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.avi.phoenixinfotech-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.avi.phoenixinfotech-1, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    Didn't find class "com.example.avi.phoenixinfotech.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.avi.phoenixinfotech-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.avi.phoenixinfotech-1, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.avi.phoenixinfotech.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is MainActivity its extending AppCompactActivity

```
    package com.example.avi.phoenixinfotech;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnScrollChangeListener;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnScrollChangeListener{

    //Creating a List of superheroes
    private List<NewsFeed> listSuperHeroes;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    //Volley Request Queue
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    //The request counter to send ?page=1, ?page=2  requests
    private int requestCount = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing Views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        //Initializing our superheroes list
        listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Calling method to get data to fetch data
        getData();

        //Adding an scroll change listener to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);

        //initializing our adapter
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, this);

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    //Request to get json from server we are passing an integer here
    //This integer will used to specify the page number for the request ?page = requestcount
    //This method would return a JsonArrayRequest that will be added to the request queue
    private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
        //Initializing ProgressBar
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        //Displaying Progressbar
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        //JsonArrayRequest of volley
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                        parseData(response);
                        //Hiding the progressbar
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        //Returning the request
        return jsonArrayRequest;
    }

    //This method will get data from the web api
    private void getData() {
        //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
        requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
        //Incrementing the request counter
        requestCount++;
    }

    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            //Creating the superhero object
            NewsFeed superHero = new NewsFeed();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                //Getting json
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding data to the superhero object
                superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                superHero.setName(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
                superHero.setPublisher(json.getString(Config.TAG_PUBLISHER));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Adding the superhero object to the list
            listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
        }

        //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //This method would check that the recyclerview scroll has reached the bottom or not
    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Overriden method to detect scrolling
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        //Ifscrolled at last then
        if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
            //Calling the method getdata again
            getData();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the base class of MainActivity?

Comment: **AppCompactActivity**

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may work 
 Open your Single instance volley Lib Class and extend **MultiDexApplication**

```html
public class AppController extends MultiDexApplication {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }
}
```